# File upload with php on a linux server dont work

Tags: php, html, linux, file-upload, upload

I want to make a website where I can upload files to a specific directory on my Linux server.

HTML:

```html
    <body>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p>File: </p>
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000000000000">
     
     <input type="file" name="FileToUpload" id="FileToUpload"> <br> <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Hochladen" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
```

PHP:

```html
    <?php
     
     
     $directory = "var/www/html/upload/";
     $file = $directory . basename($_FILES["FileToUpload"]["name"]);
  
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FileToUpload"]["name"], $file)){
      echo "File was succesfully uploaded!";
     }
     else{
      echo "ERROR";
     }
     print_r(error_get_last());

        print_r($_FILES);

    ?>
```

Php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On

upload_tmp_dir= "/var/www/html/upload/files/"

upload_max_filesize = 2048M

max_file_uploads = 20
```

output:

```
Array ( [FileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => Meme.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /var/www/html/upload/files/phpiQizaE [error] => 0 [size] => 91487 ) )
```

The folder for the uploaded image has `777` permissions and `www-data` user and group.
[image: Image showing Folder Permission]

I don't know how to make it work.
I think it's something I must change in linux, because in the middle of the search it says `The upload was succesfull`, so I don't think the php or the html are the problem...

Really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and found 2 flaws:

1. The parameter 1 should have tmp_name instead of name like this: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $file)` in place of `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FileToUpload"]["name"], $file)`
2. The location should be absolute so it should be `$directory = "/var/www/html/upload/";` instead of `$directory = "var/www/html/upload/";`

The code will work. At least it worked in mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not move file by name, but by tmp_name, rewrite this part of code to look like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $file)){
    echo "File was succesfully uploaded!";
}
```